# Third-person action fantasy videogame about afterlife factions in a war?

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I played this game around 2010 or so, at my brother's Windows PC. It looked like PS2-era 3D graphics, but I don't know if it was in any other platforms. Decidedly western in style.

The story was a war between Heaven and Hell (or demons and angels), and "spirits" or "ghosts", which were caught in the middle, as a neutral faction in Limbo/Spirit Realm or somesuch.

With each faction you played as a low grunt in the first stages (like an imp for demons, for example) and as you cleared stages, you played as increasingly powerful and more important figures, until you reached playing as their leaders in important events.

It definitely was a third person action game with combat. I THINK it might've had some light Real Time Strategy elements as well, giving orders to NPC units.

The spirit/ghost/neutral faction leader was a bald man with glowing white eyes, and a yellow/golden sword. But I might be confusing him with the angel faction's leader, unsure.

Two distinct vivid images I have was the faction select screen with the demon leader's 3D model in the left, the spirit leader in the middle, and the angel in the right, standing there, menacingly. Another one was the demon/hell faction's first stage, in which you were an imp, in a group of a dozen or so others, following orders. It was striking, and very, very cool.

I've tried finding this game before to no avail. Perhaps I didn't research enough, but there are so many games about angels and demons fighting that I couldn't for the life of me find it, each time I tried.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Indeed, this weekend has just been extremely hectic, and I didn't get around to confirming it. Thank you for the reminder. I will do so today.

Comment: No worries. :) We just always like to try to reach people before the site can fade out of their mind. I know I personally have that issue, finding a new site, posting, and then realizing weeks to months later that I never followed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's [Fallen Lords: Condemnation](https://www.gamepressure.com/games/fallen-lords-condemnation/z31891) according to my google fu

[image: Front cover of Fallen Lords: Condemnation]

> Fallen Lords: Condemnation is a three-dimensional action game, mainly about the extremely brutal fight (abundant bloodshed, cutting off body fragments, etc.). We are moved to the Afterworld, where a lot of enemies are waiting for us to defeat.
>
> Fallen Lords: Condemnation takes you beyond your own death. Declare your life, and be assigned the campaign you must follow. If you choose the Light as an Angel, you will experience the struggle of the Armies of Heaven, as you progress from a simple infantry soldier to finally become one of the chosen, the Champion of Angels. Lead the charges of the Cavalry of Virtue, unleash the power of mythical weapons like the Sword of Truth, as you battle to bring light to the world and slay the enemies of Justice. Often outnumbered, but never reluctant, the armies of angels advance like a raging wind, sweeping shadows from the darkest corners of the Afterworld, until nothing but light covers the barren landscape.
>
> Choose the Dark Side, and become a minion of evil, learning to use all means to expand a reign of chaos and malice to the Afterworld. Slay angels and subjugate the souls of dead men so they all kneel for you, and become slaves of the Lord of Darkness. Advance the story-based levels to gain control over more powerful machines of war, be able to lead a larger army. Capture angels and convert them to the Dark, corrupt the soul of men so they fight on your side. When you have assembled all the Forces of Darkness you will finally confront the enemy and, on plains of blood, defeat them and reign supreme over a world of chaos.

### Trailer